# How should an iOS app prevent consumable items from being reused?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-4.1

Probably a newbie question, I am using the [Verify Store Receipts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html) API to verify purchases of consumable items. How can I mark these items consumed so that the same receipt cannot be used again? Is there any option other than storing the used receipts?

Comment: Take a look at [MKStoreKit](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/mkstorekit-4-0-supporting-auto-renewable-subscriptions/).  It's a couple classes you compile in and it handles all this for you.

Comment: Client side libraries are no good we assume hacked clients. We need to ensure non-repetitive use server side.

Comment: Why are you looking for options other than storing the used receipts? They're not enormous and it's a fairly obvious and simple solution.

Comment: We expect many purchases of the same item(s) and the total data would grow with each purchase. I wanted to know if there was a better way such as invalidating a receipt in Apple's records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a backend service to track receipts. [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) has brilliantly simple SDKs for iOS and Android that make it easy to persist bits of data to a provided server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use iCloud (or normal UserDefaults) for that. However, you will probably prefer using your own servers.

Comment: Same issue as above, we assume hacked clients

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I think that iCloud checks for that.